# Why the images in the <img> arent showing up in the webpage?

Tags: html

I have the following HTML code, but when I try to view the page the images aren't showing, can tell me why this is? The image paths are correct.

```
<div class="content container_16">
<div id="sidebar" class="grid_4 alpha">
    <div class="widget cats">
        <div class="w-title"><?php echo $lbl_categories; ?></div>
        <ul>
            <?php wp_list_cats("sort_order=name&exclude=1&hide_empty=0"); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="main-body" class="grid_12 omega">
        <div id="ad-top" class="grid_12">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/content-top.png" alt="Some text"/>
            <img src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
    <div>
        <p>some text follows here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

While in Firebug the total div (ad-top) looks like dimmed.

Small update: When I remove the `id` from the `div`, its showing back - strange.

Comment: In the CSS, is it possible that the id ad-top has been set to display:none; ? You can check that in firebug.

Comment: nope only rule applied to ad-top is padding bottom 10. and it doesnt allow any names for id, if i use id or class name, it goes blank

Comment: i got it, its the adblock plus, because the name of the file contains the word "ad", it blocked, damn.... @frankline thanks for the help

Comment: Glad you figured it out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LINUX, make sure that you have read/write access to the images folder.

Also ensure that your images URL are correct.

Comment: im in windows, and i can see the images in the url using firebug, but only its not showing in the page

Comment: @srisar When you hover on the image link in Firebug, is it popping up the image? If yes, then check to see if the z-index property of ad-top is set correctly.

Comment: ya its popping up the image, but the divs are not absolute positioned.

Comment: @srisar What is bloginfo("template_url"); ? Does it return something? If YES, should you try and do "echo bloginfo("template_url");" ?

Comment: yes it returns the following http://127.0.0.1/malyvu/wp-content/themes/malyvutheme/images/content-top.png full path